Snowpark- Can load file from sftp and orcale into snowflake table using snowpark?
I am checking for a solution to load file from sftp server into snowflake table using snowpark -snowflake notebook
is there any direct option?

Yes: https://medium.com/snowflake/simplifying-data-ingestion-creating-a-data-pipeline-in-snowflake-with-sftp-e99033f230c2
Security:
-- sftp server credential, it could be RSA key or password, 
-- in this example using public/private key to authenticate ssh server

CREATE  SECRET sftp_aws_cred
    TYPE = password
    USERNAME = 'upatel'
    PASSWORD = '-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAACFwAAAAdzc2gtcn
....
....
683+H3R+whcAAAAAAQID
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
'
;

CREATE OR REPLACE NETWORK RULE aws_sftp_network_rule
  TYPE = HOST_PORT
  VALUE_LIST = ('yoursftpserver:22') 
  -- Port 22 is the default for SFTP, change if your port is different
  MODE= EGRESS
;

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION sftp_aws_ext_int
  ALLOWED_NETWORK_RULES = (aws_sftp_network_rule)
  ALLOWED_AUTHENTICATION_SECRETS = (sftp_aws_cred)
  ENABLED = true
;

Load from sftp:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_from_sftp
        (stage_name string, stage_dir string, sftp_remote_path string, 
            pattern string, sftp_server string ,port integer )
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'getfiles'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (sftp_aws_ext_int)
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python','pysftp','re2')
SECRETS = ('cred' = sftp_aws_cred)
AS
$$
import _snowflake
import pysftp
import re
import os
from snowflake.snowpark.files import SnowflakeFile
def getfiles(session, internal_stage, stage_dir,   remote_file_path, 
              pattern, sftp_server, port):
    sftp_cred = _snowflake.get_username_password('cred');
    sftp_host = sftp_server
    sftp_port = port
    sftp_username = sftp_cred.username
    sftp_privatekey = sftp_cred.password
    privkeyfile = '/tmp/content' + str(os.getpid())
    with open(privkeyfile, "w") as file:
      file.write(sftp_privatekey)
    full_path_name = f'{internal_stage}/{stage_dir}'
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    try:
        # if sftp server has passwrod change following line        
        with pysftp.Connection(host=sftp_host, 
              username=sftp_username, 
              private_key=privkeyfile, 
              port=sftp_port, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
            if sftp.exists(remote_file_path):
                sftp.chdir(remote_file_path)
                rdir=sftp.listdir()
                ret=[]
                for file in (rdir):
                    if re.search(pattern,file) != None:
                        sftp.get(file, f'/tmp/{file}')
                        session.file.put(f'/tmp/{file}', full_path_name, 
                          auto_compress=False, overwrite=True )
                        ret.append(file)
        return ret
    except Exception as e:
        return f" Error with SFTP : {e}"
$$;

